# I am working with Redis and it is not storing data also not giving any error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am Using **SpringBoot** and working with **Redis**. I have configured Redis for my project. Somehow it is not storing any key value and also not giving any error.

Can someone please help me out?

**Spring Boot version: 2.7.5**

- Dependency for Redis

```
<!-- start of redis dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- end of redis dependencies -->
```

- Redis configuration class
  [RedisConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFcnk.png)
- Properties file

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

- Previously I had done same configuration another project and it is working fine.